# ColdFusion: Modify combobox options in cfgrid

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs, coldfusion

I have a `<cfgrid>` with one `<cfgridcolumn>`.  I'm using the `values` attribute for that column:

```html
<cfform>
  <cfgrid name="grdBrokers"
          format="html"
          bind    ="cfc:CFC.Brokers.getGridData ( {cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize},{cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection})" 
          onChange="cfc:CFC.Brokers.editGridData( {cfgridaction},{cfgridrow},{cfgridchanged})"
          selectMode = "edit">
    <cfgridcolumn name="name" header="Name" values="Item1,Item2" >
  </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

The `values` attribute causes a combobox to appear when the user edits a cell in the `Name` column:
[image: In-cell combobox resulting from Values attribute]

I need to dynamically (without reloading the page) change the options list of that combobox.  After much research (stackoverflow.com, [raymondcamden.com](http://www.raymondcamden.com), etc.) I concluded there are no ColdFusion methods for doing this, so I figured I'd use JavaScript.  To locate the `id` for the combobox I viewed the HTML source for my page and found the following:

```html
<form name="CFForm_1" id="CFForm_1" action="/index2.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_1(this)">
  <div  id="cfgrid1344103796431" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; overflow: hidden;"></div> 
    <select id='cf_grid_select0' class='ygrid-editor'>
      <option value='Item1'>Item1</option>
      <option value='Item2'>Item2</option>
    </select> 
  <div>
  <input type="hidden" name="__CFGRID__CFForm_1__grdBrokers" value="" /></div>
</form>
```

So, the id I want is `cf_grid_select0`.  However, this element isn't found by `document.getElementById()`.  I have also inspected the page using FireBug and can't find the `cf_grid_select0` element on the DOM tab.  It's contained in `document.body.innerHTML` as raw HTML text, but not as its own element in the DOM.

Here is my code that attempts to find `cf_grid_select0`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function find( ) {
    var cbxFind = document.getElementById( 'cf_grid_select0' );

    if ( cbxFind ) alert( "Found!" );
    else           alert( "Not found!" );
  }  
</script>

<form>
  <input id="btnFind" type="button" onclick="find();" value="Find">
</form>
```

When I click the `Find` button, I get a popup saying "Not found!".

My question is: using JavaScript or jQuery, how can I locate a `<select>` that my browser obviously knows about, but doesn't *seem* to be in the DOM?  I suspect `ColdFusion.getGridObject()` might be what I'm looking for, but I can't find a way to select the combobox using that method, either.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
It appears that ColdFusion is using ExtJS to transform the `<select>` into a `ComboBox` after the page loads, apparently removing the `<select>` from the DOM.  I am now researching how to locate a ExtJS `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

I would almost certainly use jQuery! Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var $mySelect = $("#cf_grid_select0");
alert("I found it..." + $mySelect.attr("id"))

});
</script>
```

Good luck.

**NINJA EDIT**

If you're viewing the real source then it IS in the DOM. If you're viewing a "generated" JS kind of source, then it is tricky, but I think jQuery can detect new elements added to the DOM anyway.

Comment: Very interesting:

That worked, but only on page load (as you wrote it).  If I use `var $mySelect = $("#cf_grid_select0");` in my find() function to locate it when I click the Find button, it fails.  I further scanned the page source and noticed some ExtJS code that is transforming cf_grid_select0 into a ComboBox, apparently removing the original <select> from the DOM.

I'm going to try to locate and repopulate the ComboBox using ExtJS.

+1 for getting me moving in the right direction!

Comment: Well, jQuery needs to be placed within some varient of 'ready' function; whether it be 'document' or 'window' etc. I wouldn't place jQuery outside of this. jQuery is great, because it handles the whole DOM change automatically. I'm a little drunk right now, so sorry if this doesn't make too much sense.